# How can I direct a user to a new page dynamically based on a dropdown list with plain Wicket?

Tags: java, navigation, anchor, wicket

Here is my situation: the user selects a section (for example from a dropdown) such as "Section1," "Section2" or "Section3." Then he clicks the OK button (or some link).

What I need to happen: after he clicks on that button/link, he will be redirected to the selected section, e.g. `www.homepage.com/docs#section2`.

So far, I have not been able to process the form from `Link`'s `onClick` method, nor have I been able to call some `clickLink` on `Link` from the `Button` method `onSubmit()`.

I would prefer not to use AJAX or JavaScript. How can I do this?

Comment: Please show some code so we have something to work with.

Comment: there is no code so far (none relevant)

I am asking for ideas how to solve this problem. (In my opinion this is common problem and someone had to solve it before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because a Link doesn't submit the form. It just acts as a link to somewhere. To access your formdata you'll need to submit the form first. Try using a SubmitLink instead of a Link and call

```
getRequestCycle().setRequestTarget  
    (new RedirectRequestTarget("www.homepage.com/docs#section2"));
```

from the onSubmit function of the SubmitLink. 
Judging from the Javadoc this should work but I can't test it right now.

```
A RequestTarget that will send a redirect url to the browser. Use this if you 
want to direct the browser to some external URL, like Google etc, immediately. 
Or if you want to redirect to a Wicket page. If you want to redirect with a 
delay the RedirectPage will do a meta tag redirect with a delay.
```

Comment: PageParams would be nice except how would you jump to the appropriate position ... you would have to fall back to javascript again.

Comment: @Marcelo Good point indeed... I corrected my answer to fix this.

Comment: And to add to Nicktar's answer you can use the urlFor(Class clazz) method to generate the url string and just add the "#section2" depending on the chosen value on the form.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [Link.setAnchor(Component)](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/Link.html#setAnchor%28org.apache.wicket.Component%29)?

Comment: sure I did. Problem is that I need process the form first (User selection). Then create div with particular position, then setAnchor. And all that by one user click (section selection + press button/link)

I manage that by using AjaxLink and javascript (scrollTo). However I do not like it that way. I would prefer clean solution

Comment: I see. I misunderstood the question. I'd probably look into having select list that modify the anchor on the link in onSelectionChanged to start with.